# Discord JS - Await Messages - Multiple Questions

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I am making my first Discord Bot, using Discord.js - I can make it read a command `!makeraid` and the bot will ask the first question, and store the response into an array.

I want to be able to ask multiple questions like raid name, description, date, and time. I have not yet got this far, after the first question is asked, as a test i want the bot to create the embed message.

However, i cannot make it trigger/fire the next question.

```
client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!makeraid")) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        var raid = {};
        var color = ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16);
        var raidImages = {'DDS':'https://i.imgur.com/izsm8ri.jpg','GR':'https://i.imgur.com/4S9NKtF.jpg','CR':'https://i.imgur.com/EnYiWka.jpg','OR':'https://i.imgur.com/VOYDUlO.jpg'};

        message.reply('Raid Name?').then(r => r.delete(10000));
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 10000,
            errors: ['time'],
        })
        .then((collected) => {
            raid.title = collected.first().content;
            console.log(raid);
            collected.first().delete(5000);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            message.channel.send('Raid Cancelled - Too Slow!').then(r => r.delete(5000));
        });

        while ( Object.keys(raid).length > 0 ) {
            message.reply('Do you want to create the raid? Yes or No.').then(r => r.delete(10000));     
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 10000,
                errors: ['time'],
            })
            .then((collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
                    collected.first().delete();
                    var raidEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setColor('#'+color)
                        .setAuthor('Raid Bot', client.user.avatarURL)
                        .setTitle(':star::star: '+raid.title+' :star::star:')
                        .setThumbnail(client.user.avatarURL)
                        .setDescription('Some description here')
                        .addField('Date', 'Some value here', true)
                        .addField('Time', 'Some value here', true)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter('Raid created by: '+ message.member.user.tag, message.member.user.avatarURL);

                    message.channel.send(raidEmbed).then(async embedMessage => {
                        await embedMessage.react('✅');
                        await embedMessage.react('❓');
                        await embedMessage.react('');
                    });
                } else {
                    collected.first().delete();
                    message.channel.send('Raid Cancelled').then(r => r.delete(5000));
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                message.channel.send('Raid Cancelled - Too Slow! (Make)').then(r => r.delete(5000));
            });
        }

        message.delete();       
    } else if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!help")) {
        message.reply('You Suck ').then(r => r.delete(10000));
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

No errors are coming up in the terminal, it just does nothing after the first response has been collected and push into the array.

Comment: `raid` is an array, but you're setting `raid['title']`. Arrays can't have associative keys like this (i.e. anything other than consecutive integer indexes). I mean, they can, but it won't work the way you expect, and it certainly won't update `raid.length` to be greater than 0. If you want associative keys like that, use an object instead of an array.

Comment: Hey thank you for the comment, i have converted the array to an object. But unfortunately the while loop still does not run after the object has been populated.

Comment: The next issue is that `awaitMessages` looks like it's asynchronous, using promises. That means the line after your promise chain there will be executed immediately, before it's received any messages, and your object will be empty. That's why the loop isn't running. You need to delay your loop until the promise resolves, by putting it inside the `.then` callback from the promise.